# Counterexample to distance between two disjoint compact manifolds always great than some positive real number

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

As the title says, there is a theorem that says the following:

Let M,N be compact manifolds in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $M\cap N=\emptyset$. Then there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $x\in M, y\in N$, the Euclidean distance $d(x,y)>\epsilon$.

Now consider the following example:

Let $f(x) = x$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x\in [1,2)$.

Then the graphs of f and g are smooth manifolds in $\mathbb R^2$, the two are clearly bounded, and closed (since I can take any point in the curves, and any neighborhood around the point contains points outside the curves), so they are compact.

There is something wrong with this couterexample (most probably my erroneous understanding of openness and closedness), but I cannot think of why it is wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The graphs are certainly not closed---you seem to be confusing "closed" and "not open".

Comment: But if I take an open ball around some point in the curve of f, doesn't it contain points in $\mathbb R^2$ outside the curve?

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't have much bearing on whether the curve is closed or not. In particular, $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ does not include its limit point $(0, 0)$, so it is not closed in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: The point $(1,1)$ is not in the graph of $f$ but it is not an inner point in its complement set. Thus the graph of $f$ is not closed

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: The graph of $f$ is closed *as a manifold*. It is not the same thing as being closed *as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$*, so you cannot use the usual compactness criterion. It is not a compact manifold.